When I try to install Ubuntu I face some error
I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad 310 core i3 7th gen. When I tried to install Ubuntu this error showed up. I tried to enable sgx, but I couldn't find the option. Can anyone help me here how to fix this issue?


I resolved the issue. I guess my file was corrupted but I don't know how. I am pretty sure I have installed ubuntu another device few months earlier with the same bootable pendrive. After many try I have downloaded the latest version and installed it successfully.
